# Reference question: Brownian motion and surface area

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, brownian-motion

I am doing research on the hitting probability of various sets (eg. 3D convex) and   specifically how changes in perimeter/surface area change the hitting probability.

By hitting probability I mean $P(B[0,t]\cap A\neq \varnothing$ for some t).

**Question 1**) (Answered below) Say we have two bounded planes in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, one with greater surface area than the other and  equidistant from the origin. Then given a brownian motion starting from the origin, I want to get the hitting probability of each plane.
[image]

I suppose the larger surface area plane will have a great hitting probability. But what would be a rigorous way of proving that?

Thanks that is answered below.

**Question 2**)
Also, given the exact coordinates of one of the bounded planes A above, can we compute $P(T_{A}<\infty)$? How can I go about it?

$\{T_{A} <\infty\}=\{B_{1}(t)=a, |B_{2}(t)|\geq b,|B_{3}(t)|<c$ for some $t>0\}$. Here by a,b,c I mean the distance from origin, length and width  of the square $A$. 
So I have to compute: $P_{0}\{(B_{1}(t)=a)\cap (|B_{2}(t)|\geq b)\cap (|B_{3}(t)|<c)$ for some $t>0\}$=

Also, can you provide some books/papers that expose Brownian motion and surface area for more general sets?

Thnx

Comment: A plane with a greater area than another plane? Brrr...

Comment: @Did OP did specify *bounded* planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose the larger surface area plane will have a greater hitting probability. But what would be a rigorous way of proving that?

Depends on whether for each plane $A$, the center of $A$ is the nearest point of $A$ to the origin.

If yes, then you could, by symmetry, assume the smaller plane is a subset of the larger plane, to get your result.

If no, then the result could fail.

Comment: Thanks. Also, given the exact coordinates of bounded plane A in 3d, can we compute $P(T_{A}<\infty)$?

Comment: @TKM I guess that's another question

Comment: We usually do 1 question per question

Comment: okay, I will make a new one.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180360